# Unity on 13.10: Ctrl + Alt resizes the window. How to disable this?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I run an almost fresh install Ubuntu 13.10 with Unity. As soon as I press `Ctrl + Alt` (on the left part of the keyboard), current window resizes to the size of 1 / 4 of the screen. How do I disable this behavior?

Comment: I'm not too sure, but there's a setting somewhere to fix these kinds of problems in Compiz Config Settings manager.

Comment: This is not default behaviour on my 13.10. But try going to System Settings > Keyboard and then the Shortcuts tab. Make sure that it's not listed under Custom Shortcuts and then check in Windows to see what Resize Window is listed as and change accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to do this:

1. install compiz-config: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Run CompizConfig Settings Manager from the dash
3. Disable the Grid plugin (Window Management section).

That's all. It seems, this plugin was causing this behavior somehow